# Firestore optimal data structure for numbered items

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of categories which should be sorted in a certain way on the frontend. Moreover, the items within that category should be ordered as well.

Imagine that a restaurant which has several categories of food: Dinner, Dessert, Cocktails
Each of these categories is comprised of multiple items.

On a frontend, I want to display categories and items according to a certain order which can be set manually. However, I'm unsure on which data types and structure I need to utilize for that use case.

It might look like this:

```
------------------ FANCY RESTAURANT -----------------

--------- Dinner (Order 1, shown first) ------------
Dinner 1
Dinner 2

--------- Dessert (Order 2, shown second) ----------
Dessert 1
Dessert 2
Dessert 3 
--------- Cocktails (Order 3, shown third) -----------
Cocktail 1
......
```

What I had in mind is something like this:

```
restaurants (collection)
    - name, id, etc.
    - array of categories
        * map with: category_name, array of menuItems 
    - subcollection (menuItems)
```

The array of menuItems in this case would just be an array with id's of the items in this category. Ordering would happen by using the array index.

Could this be improved somehow? Doing it like this has the disadvantage that on the frontend, I would actually need to iterate over every id in the array of menuItems and have to match them with the actual menuItems stored in the subcollection. I feel like there could be an easier solution with denormalized data but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: We usually structure the database according to the queries we want to perform. What are the queries you want to perform?

Comment: @AlexMamo get a list of all restaurants, get a single restaurant, get all menuItems of a restaurant, get a list of all menuItems but categorized (e.g: dessert: [menuItem1, menuItem2], dinner:[menuItem3,menuItem4])

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment:

> get a list of all restaurants, get a single restaurant, get all menuItems of a restaurant, get a list of all menuItems but categorized (e.g: dessert: [menuItem1, menuItem2], dinner:[menuItem3,menuItem4])

A possible database schema might be:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- restaurants (collection)
         |
         --- restarantId (document)
               |
               --- name: "Fancy Restaurant"
               |
               --- menuItems (subcollection)
                    |
                    --- menuItemId (document)
                         |
                         --- name: "Pizza"
                         |
                         --- category: "dinner"
```

To get all restaurants, you need to use the following **collection** reference:

```
rootRef.collection("restaurants");
```

If you need to get a single restaurant, you need to use the following **document** reference:

```
rootRef.collection("restaurants").document(restarantId);
```

If you need to get all menu items of a restaurant, you need to use the following **collection** reference:

```
rootRef.collection("restaurants").document(restarantId).collection("menuItems");
```

If you need to get all menu items of a restaurant by category, you need to use the following **query**:

```
rootRef.collection("restaurants").document(restarantId)
    .collection("menuItems").whereEqualTo("category", "dinner");
```

Since you didn't specify the programming language you are using, I provided the code for Android but in my opinion, is similar for the other programming languages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This has helped me a lot. But how would I be able to display them according to a certain order. E.g dinner first, cocktails second, etc.

Comment: You're very welcome. Regarding an order, you can add a new property of type number or a property of type string which should start with the letter `a` for the first type of category, `b` for the second and so on, and order ascending according to it.